# Make fragment transition animate views simultaneously

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions, fragment-transitions

I am replacing a fragment A with a fragment B and animating this. Fragment B has a `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView` and a `ListView`. What I could see is that the views in fragment B are being animated separately, the `TextView` slides in with a different velocity than the list item 1 subtitle, while list item 1 title and icon appear instantly without animation, I would like the whole view to animate at the same time, is this possible to achieve?

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment existing = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.welcome_content);
    if (existing != null) {                
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            fragmentToLoad.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true);                    
            fragmentToLoad.setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT));
        }
        fragmentTransaction.remove(existing);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.welcome_content, fragmentToLoad);
    fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `android:transitionGroup="true"` to the root layout of `FragmentB`.

From [docs of `ViewGroup#setTransitionGroup(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setTransitionGroup(boolean)):

> Changes whether or not this `ViewGroup` should be treated as a single entity during Activity Transitions. If `false`, the `ViewGroup` won't transition, only its children. If `true`, the entire `ViewGroup` will transition together.